# Numbers 1 to 10 in the circles

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

> The objective is to enter the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 in the blue circles. **Doing this, the sum of the numbers has to be equal in the three connected rectangles** (a rectangle consists of 4 connected circles, my painting skills aren't the best) !
>
> Also, try to determine **the smallest possible sum in one rectangle** and try to prove it mathematically.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got:

> 20, which is minimal.

Like this:

> ```
>     9     8     10
>  4     2     3      1
>     5     7     6
> ```

Minimality proof:

> Let $R$ be the sum of a rectangle, and let $x$ and $y$ be the values of the two repeated circles. $1+\dots+10=55$. Then we have $3R=55+x+y$. This tells us $R\gt18$ and also $x+y\equiv 2\pmod3$, of which $x+y=5$ is the first possible and $x,y=2,3$ is a possibility. Above is an example, so $R=20$ is minimal.

Comment: Great ! If you want you can prove it mathematically ?